# How to create "secure" link(identifier)?

Tags: security, cryptography, uuid, guid

What if I have some resource(image, for example), and I want it to be accessible only to persons who have a link to it. How to generate such a link(identifier)? Is UUID suitable for this?

Comment: If your use case doesn't allow you to enforce authorization, UUIDs are probably your best bet. Note that the URLs may be discovered by browser extensions, page scraping if hyperlinked, etc.

Comment: I wouldn't call them "secure", just "obfuscated"

Comment: @robinsax How do they "discover" URLs? Just by scrapping pages? Is it problem for me if links are shown only to authorized users?

Comment: If links are only show to authorized users you're good. They may have browser extensions/proxies that track requests. Just depends on how much security you need. For most use cases I'll happily use UUIDs to obscure content from the general public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly how [unlisted videos](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/157177) work in YouTube. People can only see an unlisted video if they have a link to it, but there's nothing you can do to prevent them from sharing the link.

For that reason, there's no point using a UUID (effectively a 128-bit number), which would result in giant URLs. Even YouTube identifiers are only equivalent to about 64 bits. If you only have, say, 256 unlisted URLs that you want to hide from casual observers, then a random number with 2^40 possibilities (e.g., a 10-digit hex number or 8-digit [base-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base32#Crockford's_Base32) number) would be more than adequate, unless you really want to defeat brute-force attacks that would require a billion guesses to succeed in finding just one unlisted resource.

Also bear in mind that any external links from your unlisted resource could also be traced back via [Referer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) headers, not just from HTML hyperlinks but also from the inclusion of external resources like Javascript libraries and web fonts. Using the [robots exclusion standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) might help a little bit in this regard.